# Can't display graphics in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I've been recently learning Java and today I started learning graphics. When I compiled and ran the file (through the Command Prompt) it didn't display anything, and it doesn't show any error.

It does, however, create a new process "Java.exe" for about 2 seconds, but nothing shows up on the screen. Using an IDE doesn't fix the problem either.

I can run any program that doesn't use graphics in Java.

I was wondering what could the problem be, and how could I fix it?

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel{
   /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 96);
      g2.setFont(font);
      g2.drawString("Text", 40, 120);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.getContentPane().add(new Main());
      f.setSize(300, 200);
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: You can fix it, by create/edit topic on stackoverflow and **past here your code**

Comment: I'm sorry, completely forgot that, probably because I've tried at least 3 differente examples of code and none of them worked. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us a lot to go on here - are you using swing?

Most likely is that your main thread is exiting and your app is being disposed.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //1. Create the frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

    //2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //3. Create components and put them in the frame.
    //...create emptyLabel...
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //4. Size the frame.
    frame.pack();

    //5. Show it.
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```